# How to send <C-left> into Emacs term?

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp

I use this function to send raw commands to terminal:

```
(defun raw (str)
  (interactive "sKey: ")
  (term-send-raw-string (read-kbd-macro str)))
```

But `read-kbd-macro` for `<C-left>` return `[C-left]` which is not a string.

I've also try:

```
(term-send-raw-string "\C-\eOD")
```

and

```
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "<C-left>") 'term-send-raw)
```

But those also doesn't work.

How can I send C-left then?

Comment: emacs -q -nw, C-q C-left gives "^@" (a character). Try that.

Comment: @abo-abo I've try to insert `C-q C-left` and type string ^@ and both  don't work,

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work. It was just a wild guess. What are you trying to do, anyway?

Comment: "Sending C-left" to the terminal is meaningless (while the terminal may send to Emacs byte sequences that encode things like C-left, the communication in the other direction is used for display so it instead encodes things like "change color", "move cursor", "clear screen", ...).

Comment: @abo-abo I try to add command that will alow me not move one word left, one word right in Bash. Right now it move but then jump back.

Comment: But bash already has M-f and M-b. What's wrong with those?

Comment: @abo-abo I prefer to use arrows, bash have those too, but they are not send to the terminal process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the following snippet in my setup file, for the exact same purpose as you: move by words on the bash prompt using <kbd>C-<arrows></kbd>

```
(defun term-send-Cright () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[1;5C"))
(defun term-send-Cleft  () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[1;5D"))
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-<right>") 'term-send-Cright)
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-<left>")  'term-send-Cleft)
```

I found the `\e[1;5C` and `\e[1;5D` codes using the following trick:

1. run `cat >/dev/null` in a terminal
2. type <kbd>C-<left></kbd> and <kbd>C-<right></kbd> and see what is echoed back in the terminal
3. exit with <kbd>C-d</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd>

Another way to find them would be to type in a terminal: <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-<left></kbd>